# WPF - Different ItemsSource for first row of DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a DataGrid with several columns including a DataGridComboBoxColumn.

I'd like the ComboBox to offer a limited selection for the first row only.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="myDataGrid"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Direction,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectionTypesCVS}}"
                                    Header="Direction" 
                                    Width="*"/>
```

My DirectionTypeCVS is a CollectionViewSource that returns a list of DirectionType enums, "NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST". For the first row, I would like to restrict this to "NORTH" and "SOUTH".

I've tried changed the ItemsSource in the code-behind but this doesn't behave correctly. I've also tried adding a CollectionViewSource filter it doesn't appear to be being applied correctly.

What is the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get away from using a converter if you set the `AlternationCount` property of the `DataGrid` to `int.MaxValue` and use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` attached property of the parent `DataGridRow`:

```
<DataGrid ... AlternationCount="2147483647">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="myDataGrid"
                                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Direction,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                Header="Direction" 
                                Width="*">
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" 
                                     Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectionTypesCVSSpecial}}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource DirectionTypesCVS}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would offer you to use `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, so you get binding for the row and can find out an `AlternationIndex`. What you will need to do is to write a converter.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="..." AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2147483647">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Direction, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multivalcnv}">
                                <Binding Source="{StaticResource yourStr}"/>
                                <Binding Path="AlternationIndex" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
public class MultValConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(values != null && values.Length == 2 && values[1] is int)
            if((int)(values[1]) == 0)
            {
                return new List<string> { "Do filter the values[0]" };
            }
            else
                return values[0];
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("It's a one way converter.");
    }
}
```